# Flutter: How to detect that the app is running on LD Player

Tags: android, flutter, dart, security, android-emulator

I am working in a Flutter app with some security requirements, one of them is to prevent the app from working in Emulators, just real devices, in order to prevent the screenshots and screen recordings from the Emulators.

I have used [safe_device](https://pub.dev/packages/safe_device) and [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) packages to detect whether the app is running on Emulator or Physical device and every thing is working fine but when I tried `LD Player` Emulator the packages failed to detect that it is emulator because it is very good at mocking the real device.

So any ideas to detect that the device is running on `LD Player`?

Here is the output from `device_info_plus` which might be helpful:

```
{
  "id": "N2G48B",
  "host": "ubuntu",
  "tags": "release-keys",
  "type": "user",
  "model": "ASUS_Z01QD",
  "board": "SM-G975N",
  "brand": "asus",
  "device": "aosp",
  "product": "SM-G975N",
  "display": "N2G48B",
  "hardware": "android_x86",
  "androidId": null,
  "bootloader": "unknown",
  "version": {
    "baseOS": "",
    "sdkInt": 25,
    "release": "7.1.2",
    "codename": "REL",
    "incremental": "V9.5.8.0.OCACNFA",
    "previewSdkInt": 0,
    "securityPatch": "2017-10-05"
  },
  "fingerprint": "google/android_x86/x86:7.1.2/N2G48B/V9.5.8.0.OCACNFA:user/release-keys",
  "manufacturer": "asus",
  "supportedAbis": [
    "x86",
    "armeabi-v7a",
    "armeabi"
  ],
  "systemFeatures": [
    "android.hardware.sensor.proximity",
    "android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer",
    "android.software.controls",
    "android.hardware.faketouch",
    "android.hardware.usb.accessory",
    "android.software.backup",
    "android.hardware.touchscreen",
    "android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch",
    "android.software.print",
    "android.hardware.ethernet",
    "android.software.activities_on_secondary_displays",
    "android.hardware.wifi.rtt",
    "com.google.android.feature.PIXEL_2017_EXPERIENCE",
    "android.software.voice_recognizers",
    "com.google.lens.feature.CAMERA_INTEGRATION",
    "android.software.picture_in_picture",
    "android.hardware.fingerprint",
    "android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope",
    "android.hardware.audio.low_latency",
    "android.software.vulkan.deqp.level",
    "com.google.android.feature.PIXEL_2018_EXPERIENCE",
    "android.hardware.opengles.aep",
    "android.hardware.bluetooth",
    "android.hardware.camera.autofocus",
    "com.google.android.feature.GOOGLE_BUILD",
    "android.hardware.telephony.gsm",
    "android.hardware.telephony.ims",
    "android.software.sip.voip",
    "android.hardware.vr.high_performance",
    "android.hardware.usb.host",
    "android.hardware.audio.output",
    "android.software.verified_boot",
    "android.hardware.camera.flash",
    "android.hardware.camera.front",
    "android.hardware.sensor.hifi_sensors",
    "android.hardware.se.omapi.uicc",
    "android.hardware.screen.portrait",
    "android.hardware.nfc",
    "com.google.android.feature.TURBO_PRELOAD",
    "android.hardware.sensor.ambient_temperature",
    "com.nxp.mifare",
    "android.hardware.sensor.stepdetector",
    "android.software.home_screen",
    "android.hardware.microphone",
    "android.software.autofill",
    "android.software.securely_removes_users",
    "android.software.vr.mode",
    "com.google.android.feature.PIXEL_EXPERIENCE",
    "android.hardware.bluetooth_le",
    "android.hardware.sensor.compass",
    "android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.jazzhand",
    "android.hardware.sensor.barometer",
    "android.software.app_widgets",
    "android.software.input_methods",
    "android.hardware.sensor.light",
    "android.hardware.vulkan.version",
    "android.software.companion_device_setup",
    "android.software.device_admin",
    "com.google.android.feature.WELLBEING",
    "android.hardware.wifi.passpoint",
    "android.hardware.camera",
    "com.google.android.feature.ZERO_TOUCH",
    "android.hardware.screen.landscape",
    "android.software.device_id_attestation",
    "android.hardware.ram.normal",
    "android.software.managed_users",
    "android.software.webview",
    "android.hardware.sensor.stepcounter",
    "android.hardware.camera.capability.manual_post_processing",
    "com.google.ar.core.depth",
    "android.hardware.camera.any",
    "android.hardware.camera.capability.raw",
    "android.software.connectionservice",
    "android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct",
    "android.hardware.location.network",
    "android.software.cts",
    "android.software.sip",
    "android.hardware.camera.capability.manual_sensor",
    "android.software.app_enumeration",
    "com.google.android.apps.dialer.SUPPORTED",
    "android.hardware.camera.level.full",
    "android.hardware.wifi.direct",
    "android.software.live_wallpaper",
    "com.google.android.feature.GOOGLE_EXPERIENCE",
    "android.software.ipsec_tunnels",
    "com.google.android.feature.EXCHANGE_6_2",
    "android.software.freeform_window_management",
    "android.hardware.audio.pro",
    "android.hardware.nfc.hcef",
    "android.hardware.location.gps",
    "android.software.midi",
    "android.hardware.nfc.any",
    "android.hardware.nfc.hce",
    "android.hardware.wifi",
    "android.hardware.location",
    "android.hardware.vulkan.level",
    "android.hardware.wifi.aware",
    "android.software.secure_lock_screen",
    "android.hardware.telephony",
    "android.software.file_based_encryption",
    null
  ],
  "isPhysicalDevice": true,
  "supported32BitAbis": [
    "x86",
    "armeabi-v7a",
    "armeabi"
  ],
  "supported64BitAbis": []
}
```

Comment: You should check if the app can still be recorded with the tool  `scrcpy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to check for the existence of these folders, if any of them exists, then it is an `LD Player`.

```
'/storage/emulated/0/storage/secure',
'/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.ld.appstore'
```

I have implemented a method to take a list of folders paths and return true if any of them exists, which is the following:

```
bool anyFolderExists(List<String> foldersPaths) {
   for (String folderPath in foldersPaths) {
     if (Directory(folderPath).existsSync()) {
       return true;
     }
   }
   return false;
}
```

and I'm using it like this:

```
List<String> harmfulFoldersPaths = [
  '/storage/emulated/0/storage/secure',
  '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.ld.appstore',
];

if(anyFolderExists(harmfulFoldersPaths))
{
    print('LD Player Detected!');
}
```

Also I am using these two values from the output of [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) package to decide that the app is working on an Emulator because they seems very generic:

```
"host": "ubuntu",
"device": "aosp",
```

I am using them like the following:

```
final androidInfo = await deviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo;

if (androidInfo.host == 'ubuntu' && androidInfo.device == 'aosp') {
    print('LD Player Detected!');
}
```

But to be honest, I am afraid of this approach because I do not want to block any user by mistake, so I am using them with [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/products/remote-config) to enable/disable it at any time but until now I am enabling them without any problem recorded.

Comment: this works good for ld player 4 but for ld player 9 not working

Answer (score -2):

Check this Package
https://pub.dev/packages/safe_device

```
bool isRealDevice = await SafeDevice.isRealDevice;
```

this method returns false if running device is an emulator

Comment: I have mentioned in the question that this package fails to detect `LD Player`